# SQLite DELETE using WITH statement

Tags: sql, graph, sqlite, tree, cycle

I have exactly one cycle of length 3 in my graph of roads. I'm trying to delete a road that goes from A-B and B-A that is part of the cycle. If I delete the one road it will remove the cycle and make my graph a tree. I'm able to find a road that does that by using a **with** statement. However, I want to then delete from the original table based on what I found but I seem to be unable to use a delete statement in my code. I've heard of "joins" but I'm not sure how I could use it here and would appreciate some advice.

The following code finds multiple roads that contribute to the cycle of length 3 but I limited it to 1 because I only want to delete one road.

```
%%sql 
with cycle as(
select s1.A as s1, s3.A as s3
from streets s1, streets s2, streets s3
where s1.B = s2.A and s2.B = s3.A and s3.B = s1.A
limit 1)

select A, B
from streets, cycle
where (s1 = A and s3 = B) or (s3 = A and s1 = B)
```

Returns:

[image]

I want to delete the two rows that match these A and B values in my original table thus deleting the road between GadgetCo and Thing Industries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `exists` for the matching conditions in the `where` clause:

```
with cycle as (
      select s1.A as s1, s3.A as s3
      from streets s1 join
           streets s2 
           on s1.B = s2.A join
           streets s3
           on s2.B = s3.A and s3.B = s1.A
      limit 1
     )
delete from streets
    where exists (select 1
                  from cycle c
                  where (streets.A = c.s1 and streets.B = c.s3) or
                        (streets.A = c.s3 and streets.B = c.s1)
                 );
```

Notice that I replaced your implicit joins with proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @dj1121 . . . `exists` is just checking for the existence of a row.  Something needs to come after the `select` and I find `1` the easiest to type.  So that is what I typically use.

Comment: `exists` ignores the contents of the rows (and does not even compute them), so this is where I think `select *` is justified.